# How to add drop down property into biztalk pipeline component

Tags: c#, biztalk, pipeline, biztalk-2010

i'm trying to add a drop down design-property into a pipeline component. I found this article

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dd732ffc-0372-4710-a849-370bbdb65419/custom-pipeline-component-with-an-enum-property-to-display-a-custom-drop-down-list?forum=biztalkgeneral

and i followed all steps. The result is that i can see drop down into pipeline properties in visual studio but when i associate it to receive port i can only see text box and not dropdown property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, that is the expected behavior.

The Pipeline UI in BizTalk Administrator is completely different from the UI in Visual Studio and the extended controls are only supported in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the clarification-  my above suggestions (my reply in the [referenced MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dd732ffc-0372-4710-a849-370bbdb65419/custom-pipeline-component-with-an-enum-property-to-display-a-custom-drop-down-list?forum=biztalkgeneral)) would only show the dropdown list during the design time ( in the visual studio) and this doesn't apply to BizTalk admin console.

In-fact even for the out-of-box components like XML Assembler, validator etc the flashy controls like drop-down list or the schema selector doesn't appear in the Admin console (except for Boolean datatype properties). They are available only during design time in Visual studio not in Admin console or for per-instance configurations. For example for XML-Assembler you have some properties like "Add processing instructions" or "Processing Instruction scope" they all have drop down list with values which you can select to assign in Visual studio but when you deploy the pipeline and see those assigned values in admin console they appear with values like 0,1 (index of the value in the list/collection). I realize not many have noticed this behavior for the out-of-box component's properties (as how they appear in Visual studio and in admin console)

Answer (score 0):

The following link explains how to do it
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dd732ffc-0372-4710-a849-370bbdb65419/custom-pipeline-component-with-an-enum-property-to-display-a-custom-drop-down-list?forum=biztalkgeneral