# How to implement a dropdown list in BizTalk custom pipeline

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016, biztalk-2020

I have search for how to implement a dropdownlist of choose in a BizTalk custom Pipeline that's show in the BizTalk Admin console part of the property windows, but the samples doesn't work for BizTalk 2020.

Can anyone show me a working sample for BizTalk 2016/2020 how to implement dropdown Enum list that shows in the admin console.

I have made a Enum and implemented a public property which return my Enum type, but this doesn't work.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the sample you tried to use?  What doesn't work?  Do you get an error, or is it simply still a text field?   See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813691/how-to-add-drop-down-property-into-biztalk-pipeline-component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't

Even Microsoft couldn't implement that properly as per the bug on my blog [BizTalk 2013 R2 known bugs, issues & quirks](https://cdijkgraaf.wordpress.com/2016/08/12/biztalk-2013-r2-known-bugs-issues-quirks/) where the flat file assembler has a drop down that does not work in the Admin Console.

> CHANGING THE TARGETCHARSET IN THE XML OR FLAT FILE ASSEMBLER HAS NO EFFECT IN THE BIZTALK ADMINISTRATION CONSOLE

Also, see this earlier post for BizTalk 2010 [How to add drop down property into biztalk pipeline component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813691/how-to-add-drop-down-property-into-biztalk-pipeline-component) and the linked MSD thread that explains that although you can get the drop down working in Visual Studio, in the Admin Console it will be an Int or String

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer.. i can understand why MS not implementing the dropdown function for the admin console, it will be very usefull.. no one can remember index of the implemented enum.